# Is PowerPoint 2003 supported by Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I am trying to decide if I should upgrade to Windows 8 and one of my mission critical programs is PowerPoint 2003. I was wondering if Windows 8 x64 has PowerPoint 2003 support.

Comment: I don't consider this too local, because 2 people are giving me different answers and I don't want to spent 2 hours attempting to install Windows 8 if it won't work with the same software that runs in Wine.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Windows Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/en-US/CompatCenter/ProductViewerWithUpdatedFilters?Architecture=X64&CurrentPage=0&TotalPages=16&ShowCriteria=10%20Results%20Per%20Page&SortCriteria=Relevance&IsSearchWithinFilterAvailable=False&FilterByCompatibility=ALL&TextSearch=Microsoft%20Office%202003&AbsolutePage=-1&ProductName=Microsoft%20Office%202003) MS Office 2003 is **NOT** compatible with Windows 8. However for earlier builds of Windows 8, RTM (build 9200) (with the Developer Preview, Consumer Preview and Release Preview) the compatibility center said Office 2003 was compatible.

Personally I don't see any reason as to why Office 2003 won't work with Windows 8, since it was compatible with earlier builds of Windows 8.

Comment: Office 2003 Service Pack 3 is compatible with Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I beg to differ from the previous answer.
According to [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Software&Name=Microsoft%20Office%20PowerPoint%202003%20Service%20Pack%203&Vendor=Microsoft&ModelOrVersion=11&Locale=1033&BreadcrumbPath=powerpoint%202003&tempOsid=win8) PowerPoint 2003 with SP3 is compatible with Windows 8 (and 7, obviously).

When you install any of the last few versions of Office onto a 64 bit OS the installation actually suggests you use the 32 bit version as you may encounter various issues with other software if you use the 64 bit version of Office. So, yes, it should be fine.

Also, according to the [Microsoft support lifecycle](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=Office%202003&Filter=FilterNO) page and [PowerPoint 2003 support](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=PowerPoint%202003&Filter=FilterNO) page you should be getting at least some form of extended support for Office 2003 up until 2014. So you would think that it would need to work on what will be a 2 year old OS by then. Sweeping assumption, I admit, but reasonable, I think, for this particular product.

Comment: Just to clarify, according to Windows Compatibility Center, Microsoft Office Power Point 2003 **Service Pack 3** is compatible with Windows 8, earlier versions of MS Office 2003 are **NOT** compatible. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/ProductViewerWithDefaultFilters?TempOsid=win8&Locale=en-us&TextSearch=PowerPoint%2B2003&Type=Both&CurrentPage=0&TotalPages=1&ShowCriteria=0&SortCriteria=Relevance&Compatibility=Unknown&LastRequested=14

Comment: @RakibAnsary - Is there a difference only Office 2003 Service Pack 3 is supported by Microsoft.